# Animate linked rig shared in multiple scenes in same .blend

Tags: animation, rigging, linked-data, scene

I am working on a project where a car is speeding in a city with blender 2.8. Each shots are separated by scenes. I can link my car from another .blend, make a proxy to animate it and everything is fine. When I switch to another scene and go trough the same process, the first scene is now broken.

After testing, I came to the conclusion that making proxies is the problem.

What would be the correct workflow to animate from a linked .blend between multiple scenes?

Thank you for your time!